# List comprehension that ignores NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to build a list comprehension that has a conditional to not import nan values, but not having luck. Below is the current code along with the resulting output. What conditional will remove the nans from the list?

```
def generate_labels(filtered_df, columnName):
    return[
        {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in 
        filtered_df[columnName].unique() 
    ]

generate_labels(df, 'Region')


#Output  


[{'label': 'Americas', 'value': 'Americas'},
     {'label': 'EMEA', 'value': 'EMEA'},
     {'label': nan, 'value': nan},
     {'label': 'APAC ', 'value': 'APAC '}]
```

Comment: This is a dictionary comprehension.

Comment: `filtered_df[columnName].dropna().unique()` ?

Comment: @Steve , see the brackets on the ends.

Comment: @Maksim I do now. The classic list of dictionaries. I shouldn't have missed that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def generate_labels(filtered_df, columnName):
    return[
        {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in filtered_df[columnName].dropna().unique() 
    ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a condition in your list comprehension expression. Something like:

```
import math

def generate_labels(filtered_df, columnName):
    return[
        {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in 
        filtered_df[columnName].unique() 
        if not math.isnan(i)
    ]
```

There are a number of ways where you can check if a value is nan or not. You can also use the numpy version if that's what you prefer.

Comment: You actually don't need `math`, pandas already has it built in with numpy: `pd.np.isnan(i)`.

Comment: @Idlehands Good point, there are multiple ways we can do it, if pandas is already loaded, it's probably simpler that we don't need to load another library.