# List comprehension that skips NaN values

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, nan

I know there is a similar question to this already
([List comprehension that ignores NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938346/list-comprehension-that-ignores-nan))
but the solutions do not fit my case.

I have a list of tuples. I'm using a list comprehension to generate a list of subtuples from this list of tuples. Depending on the data file I'm reading in, sometimes I have NaN (`np.nan`) values. In these cases, my list comprehension is returning tuples of nans `(nan, nan)`, but I'd prefer it didn't.

Below is an illustration of what I've tried. It doesn't give me the output I want, but doesn't give an error either:

```
   list_values = 
        [('A', 1., 2., 1),
         ('B', 3., 4., 1),
         ('C', 5., 6., 1),
       ('D', nan, nan, 1),
       ('E', nan, nan, 1),
       ('F', nan, nan, 1)])
```

I thought this would work, but it doesn't:

```
pairs = [tuple((x[1] + x[3], x[2] + x[3])) for x in list_values if x[1] is not np.nan]
```

It returns this:

```
[(2.0, 3.0), (4.0, 5.0), (6.0, 7.0), (nan, nan), (nan, nan), (nan, nan)]
```

Whereas I would like:

```
[(2.0, 3.0), (4.0, 5.0), (6.0, 7.0)]
```

I don't know why my if conditions are doing nothing at all. Any insights appreciated, thank you!

Comment: That's a list comprehension in the question you linked. There's no error in the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`is not np.nan` isn't how you do a NaN check. It's an identity check for the specific object `np.nan`, and most NaNs are not going to be that particular object.

`math.isnan` is a NaN check, and you can apply that check to the elements of `x` with a genexp. (Also, you don't need to call `tuple` on your tuples.)

```
pairs = [(x[1] + x[3], x[2] + x[3]) for x in list_values
                                    if all(not math.isnan(elem) for elem in x[1:])]
```

Comment: Right...whoops! I certainly should have clicked that, of course, x is a tuple, but in any case I wouldn't have thought of math.isnan as a solution. Thank you!

Comment: I've edited my original question to make it about specifically using 'is not np.nan' on the elements of a tuple, since that aspect is more likely to be of use to others. Thanks again.